# MongoDB: getting ObjectId of last inserted document with multiple, concurrent writers?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongomapper, nosql

Consider the following scenario with MongoDB:

Three writers (A,B,C) insert a document into the same collection.

A inserts first, followed by B, followed by C.

How can we guarantee A retrieves the ObjectId of the document he inserted and not B's document or C's document?  Do we need to serialize the writes (i.e., only permit B to write after A inserts and retrieves the ObjectId), or does MongoDB offer some native functionality for this scenario?

Thanks!

We're on Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the normal pattern here is for the driver to allocate the ObjectId and then you know what it is for the insert even before the server gets it.

Comment: also the findAndModify command returns the object id allocated; there you would do an upsert. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the `_id` value in your client applications (writers) before inserting the document.  This way you don't need to rely on the server generating the ObjectId an retrieving the correct value.  Most MongoDB language drivers will do this for you automatically if you leave the _id blank.